# SQL : Record Existance Check in another table

Tags: mysql, sql

My requirement is below .

I have two tables let's call them Table A and Table B :

```
PARTNER_ID      PARTNER_Registration        Partner_PANNUMBER
----------
1               11                          AB1
2               22                          AB2
3               33                          AB3
4               44                          AB4
5               55                          AB5
6               66                          AB6
7               77                          AB5
8               88                          AB8
```

i Will have another table B which contains PID , Preg, Ppan as follows

```
PID PREG    PPAN
----------
1   11      AB1
2   22      AB2
3   33      AB3
4   44  
5           AB5
    66      AB6
```

Now I should create a column Output in table A and have output as follows

```
PARTNER_ID  PARTNER_Registration    Partner_PANNUMBER   Output
----------
1           11                      AB1                 All three Found
2           22                      AB2                 All three Found
3           33                      AB3                 All three found
4           44                      AB4                 PPAN NOT FOUND 
5           55                      AB5                 PARTNER_Registration Not Found in TABLE B
6           66                      AB6                 PARTNER_ID Not found in Table B
7           77                      AB5                 PARTNER_ID, PARTNER_Registration Not found in Table B
8           88                      AB8                 None of them Found in Table B
```

Can some one help me find an easy way to acheive this in SQL,

I would like to populate which values of 3 columns are not present in another and update output column accordingly..

Thanks

Comment: Can you format the question more readably?

Comment: @Barmar, OP seems new to the site, So I have done it on his behalf.

Answer (score 2):

I would just add up the number of matches:

```
select a.*,
       ( exists (select 1 from b where b.PID = a.PARTNER_ID) +
         exists (select 1 from b where b.PREG = a.PARTNER_Registration) +
         exists (select 1 from b where b.PPAN = a.Partner_PANNUMBER)
       ) as num_matches
from a;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use multiple `LEFT JOIN` with table B, and test which ones produce `NULL` values.

```
SELECT a.*,
    CASE WHEN b1.pid IS NOT NULL AND b2.preg IS NOT NULL AND b3.ppan IS NOT NULL
            THEN 'All three found'
        WHEN b1.pid IS NULL AND b2.preg IS NULL AND p3.ppan IS NULL
            THEN 'None of them found in Table B'
        ELSE CONCAT(CONCAT_WS(', '
                        IF(b1.pid IS NULL, 'Partner_ID', NULL),
                        IF(b2.preg IS NULL, 'Partner_Registration', NULL),
                        IF(b3.ppan IS NULL, 'PPAN', NULL)),
                   ' not found in Table B') AS Output
FROM TableA AS a
LEFT JOIN TableB AS b1 ON a.partner_id = b1.pid
LEFT JOIN TableB AS b2 ON a.partner_registration = b2.preg
LEFT JOIN TableB AS b3 ON a.partner_pannumber = b.ppan
```

`CONCAT_WS()` will ignore null values, so with the `IF` statements inverting `NULL` with the names of the missing values, you get the list of results you want.

Comment: How to handle all Not matched case ??

Comment: Added another `WHEN` for that.

Answer (score 0):

I would use multiple `LEFT JOIN` because of the `use case` of OP where we can manipulate the null values means missing in table2 to achieve the exact output you want.

The query looks big but it is just manipulating the string using specific `string functions` to get the final string output.

```
select a.partner_id
      ,a.partner_registration
      ,a.partner_pannumber
      ,case 
         when chk = ''
         then 'All three found'
       else
        concat(case (length(chk) - length(replace(chk,',','')))
                when 3
                 then 'None of them found'
                when 1
                 then replace(chk,',',' not found')
                else
                 regexp_replace(chk,'[,]',' not found',1,2)
                end
              ,' in table2'
              )
       end Remarks
  from
(
select a.*
      ,concat(case when pi.pid is null then 'Partner Id,' else '' end
             ,case when pr.preg is null then 'Partner Registration,' else '' end
             ,case when pp.ppan is null then 'PPAN,' else '' end
             ) chk
  from table1 a
left join table2 pi
on a.partner_id = pi.pid
left join table2 pr
on a.partner_registration = pr.preg
left join table2 pp
on a.partner_pannumber = pp.ppan
) a
```

P.S. I personally like the answer with usage of `concat_ws` as it has less code but you need a little modification for `non of them match in ...` case.